# Access sharepoint online via rest and ntlm or similiar

Tags: rest, sharepoint, office365

We are trying to ask get questions to the sharepoint api for example

```
https://domain.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle'('List')'/Items
```

We have been trying to access our sites API via REST API. We have tried many different ways and looked trough a lot of Microsoft Documentation but it seems we have misunderstood something in regards to how to authenticate us because we get

```
Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource
```

We use Office365 and Sharepoint Online. Can I not use username password somehow or do I have to design a flow for authentication using the token request etc? Can I in that case try it with curl somehow?

We have tried to use curl to simulate it:

```
curl https://domain.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle'('List')'/Items -v --ntlm --negotiate -u username:password
```

Comment: Is the user making this request accessing to the site anonymously?

Comment: Yes i would assume that they are since this is the only request that i am sending them